# Flutter pub get failed with (1; The system cannot find path specified)

Tags: flutter, dart

When I tried to run flutter in command prompt using "flutter run command" I got "pub get failed (1; The system cannot find the path specified.)" and I did not found where pub is located in my pc.

Comment: What is the path therein you commated `flutter run`

Comment: It is in my Desktop

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well and came about several situations that could cause it.

**First one:** It could be a broken path in your env variables. You can check all paths by doing a simple "echo %PATH%" in your terminal and removing those that don't point to a valid location.

**Second one:** Make sure that your project path doesn't include an '&' as stated on this issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41547

**Third one:** Another one that I found is that after uninstalling Anaconda it left out an AutoRun key in the command processor registry.

Check these places in regedit for broken links:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor